# Login page in base path

Tags: php, yii

While I type `localhost/yiitest` in the address bar I want to view the login page. I searched the web, but wasn't able to find out how to do this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: May i know why given -1 ?? Editer is not working while giving enter thats not my prob okay.

Comment: Sally, what do you see instead?

Comment: ("localhost/yiitest") I see the welcome page of yii framework, when I searched i got ans as default controller, but I do not know how to integrate html login template, need help here.

Answer (score 0):

If youre using yii1, add a filter to your controller:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array('accessControl'); // perform access control for CRUD operations
}

public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'allow', // allow authenticated users to access all actions
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny'),
    );
}
```

If not logged user try to access any page, he will be redirected to `site/login` (you can change it in config). Of course if u add this accessRules in `SiteController` you have to add additional rule to allow not logged in users to access `actionLogin()`.

Comment: I am using bootstrap code generator. If not logged in it goes directly to login page. what i asked is when i typed "localhost/yiitest/" this url loads login page.

Comment: Then change default controller in the config main.php

`return array(
    'name' => 'Web Application',
    'defaultController' => 'home',    // add this line
    ......
);`

And in default controller add property `public $defaultAction = 'login';`

Comment: I am using html theme template so I do not know how to integrate it in contrloller.